# Blazor Server App; Refresh in browser a property that is a class comes back nul

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

App: Blazor Server .NET 5
Using Entity Framework Core
DB; Azure SQL DB

All Ok except for if I refresh the browser, the Helper properties returned by GetActivitys() are null.
Does the Helper property in Activity need a tag?

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Activity> Activitys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Helper> Helpers { get; set; }
   }

   public class DataAccessService : IDataAccessService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public DataAccessService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<Activity>> GetActivitys()
        {
           var list = await _context.Activitys.ToListAsync<Activity>();
               return list;
        }
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Task")]
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("Task")]
        public string Task { get; set; }

        [Column("Helper")]
        [JsonPropertyName("Helper")]
        public Helper Helper { get; set; }
   }

    public class Helper
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Name")]
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("Name")
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include navigational properties after materializing your query via `.ToListAsync()`, you must add a chained method `.Include(activity => activity.Helper)` before materialization.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more, thanks. 

Do you mean something like:  

_context.Activitys.ToListAsync() 

Becomes

_context.Activitys.Include(activity => activity.Helper).ToListAsync()

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: As it turned out  i had 2 properties that are entities. When I did this for both it worked; Thanks Is there a good reference on this requirement?  The only reference I can find is this post!! Thanks again.